# INSERT INTO fallido en 000webhost

Tags: php, sql, insert, hosting

Acabo de subir un proyecto a 000webhost ya es gratis y es para una tarea.
Pero al hacer una INSERT me dice que si se hiso pero en realidad no se hiso y en localhost si hace el INSERT de forma correcta.
Este es el codigo:

```
               $statement = $conexion->prepare(
                    "INSERT INTO cliente1 (Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, Email, Tel, pass, idRol)
                    VALUES (:nombre, :apellidop, :apellidom, :email, :tel, :pass, :idr)"
                    );
                    
                    $statement->execute(array(
                        ':nombre' => $nombre,
                        ':apellidop' => $apellidop,
                        ':apellidom' => $apellidom,
                        ':email' => $email,
                        ':tel' => $tel,
                        'pass' => $pass,
                        'idr' => '2',
                    ));
                    
                        if ($statement == true) {
                            ?>
                            <script>
                                alert('Cuenta creada exitosamente');
                                //location.href='login.php';
                            </script>
                            <?php
                        }else {
                            ?>
                            <script>
                                alert('Error al crear la cuenta, intente de nuevo');
                            </script>
                            <?php
                        }
```

Me sale el mensaje de que si se creo la cuenta, pero en la BD no esta registrada.

Esta es la tabla (Los datos son ficticios):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que tengo que hacer??

Comment: Depura tu query usando [*`errorInfo`*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php) para ver si se obtiene algún mensaje de error asociado

Comment: Saludos. ¿**$statement** es un variable booleana/flag o tu variable de conexión; por lo regular cualquier valor distinto de **0** *(cero)* (incluso si es un valor **null**) es interpretado como **true**.